# Select row by specifying date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, sql-server-ce

I have this record in my table

```
Name   UserName     Password     DateAdded
skype  someusername somepassword 05/06/2012 01:18:50
```

I am trying to execute this statement but it always fails.

Some attempts: (all fails)

```
Select * from Passwords where DateAdded = '05/06/2012 01:18:50'
Select * from Passwords where DateAdded = #05/06/2012 01:18:50#
Select * from Passwords where DateAdded = '06/05/2012 01:18:50'
Select * from Passwords where DateAdded = '2012/06/05 01:18:50'
Select * from Passwords where DateAdded = '2012/05/06 01:18:50'
Select * from Passwords where DateAdded like '2012/06/05 01:18:50'
```

The column `DateAdded` in my database is of type `datetime` and not `nvchar`.

I am new in SQL, what is wrong with this query?

Comment: When you say `fails` what actually happens?  Do you get an error message? What does it say?  Is it unexpected results?  What are they?

Comment: If you are getting no results it's probably because the DateTime type is more precise than a second (down to thousands of a second), so unless you got lucky and happened to get an insert with no fractional seconds, or happened to hand-specify the date at insert,  you won't get any results with your query.  With DateTime's you usually use <, >, or BETWEEN unless you are specifically truncating the DateTimes you enter so that you can know, for example, that you don't have to worry about fractional seconds.

Comment: i try it but no work, the problem is that it returns 0 rows nothing happens . in order to make it work i have to use the > instead of = which is wrong.

Comment: so in order to make it work i should use between ?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing.  It is possible to trim off the fractional seconds before or at insertion.  It is also possible to trim off the fractional seconds in the query at comparison time, but that is less performant.  Can you update your post with the reason why you need to run queries that involve precision down to the second, or more generally what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps have fractional seconds stored?  Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Passwords
    WHERE DateAdded BETWEEN '2012-05-06 01:18:50' AND '2012-05-06 01:18:51';
```

(I prefer that format of datetime literal because it's unambiguous, but yours should work as well.  Tsql will take [almost anything you throw at it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Comment: still nothing .. always am getting 0 records.

Comment: CmdString.CommandText = "Select * from Passwords where DateAdded BETWEEN '2012/05/06 01:18:50' AND '2012/05/06 01:18:50'"
        DS.Clear() 'clear the dataset
        TA.Fill(DS, "MyTable") ' refill my table 
        BS.DataSource = DS.Tables("MyTable") 'assign the binding source
        BindControls() ' bind my controls textboxes labels ..

Comment: Can you try honing in on exactly what date it thinks it is?  For example, try using WHERE DateAdded > '2012-05-06 01:18:50'.  If it's there, then try WHERE DateAdded > '2012-05-07 01:18:50'.  If it's there, then back it off to, say, WHERE DateAdded > '2012-05-06 13:18:50'.  By process of elimination, if you can figure out what date and time SQL Server thinks it is, you'll probably figure out why it's giving you an unexpected result.  Maybe it has to do with timezone conversion or date format.

Comment: Can you try querying the database directly using some sort of direct database interface instead of via your code first?  Validate that the query and data work.  If it does, then figure out what's wrong with your code.  I don't see anything in your query or data that would cause this to fail.

Comment: i try to excecute it by selecting the a column which is my ID column integer value . the same code is working if use Select * from Passwords where ID=4 . the problem comes accross with selecting DateTime field. i have try the example you said DateAdded >'2012/05/06 01:18:50' and it works but is not correct to use > becuase i want excactly to return me only one record

Comment: I know, but what I'm saying is for debugging, you need to hone in on exactly what value your database THINKS is in the column.  What do you get if you try WHERE DateAdded > '2012-05-07 01:18:50' (one day later)?  Do you still get the row in your resultset?

Comment: if i use the WHERE DateAdded > '2012-05-07 01:18:50' it returns me 2 records 1st record is 05/06/2012 01:18:50 2nd record is 05/06/2012 03:19:09